# XSS using SVG: Is AllowScriptAccess attribute ignored?

Tags: xss, javascript, svg

I was experimenting with some Anti-XSS solutions, and during my research, I found following the XSS vector in a cheatsheet:

```
<EMBED SRC="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxuczpzdmc9Imh0dH A6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcv MjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hs aW5rIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjAiIHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxOTQiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAw IiBpZD0ieHNzIj48c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9InRleHQvZWNtYXNjcmlwdCI+YWxlcnQoIlh TUyIpOzwvc2NyaXB0Pjwvc3ZnPg==" type="image/svg+xml" AllowScriptAccess="always"></EMBED>
```

Since the SVG is not loaded as picture, but instead as "embed", its JavaScript content is executed.

I have two questions:

1) Is there a way to disable JavaScript? If I replace "always" with "never", it still executes the JavaScript.

2) I would like to give trusted users the ability to include HTML content to an internal website. I want to give them a lot of freedom, like adding pictures, inserting YouTube videos, maybe even Google Maps iframes and stuff, as long as they don't execute JavaScript. But if I would give them access to the HTML "embed" tags, do I need to worry about JavaScripts/XSS execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, the attribute `AllowScriptAccess` only works in context of Flash-Objects, as referenced [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reviewing_Flash_Applications#Accessing_JavaScript). It does not appear to be part of the embed-tag definition, as [these](https://books.google.de/books?id=o_3_WQSHkvgC&pg=PA232&lpg=PA232&dq=AllowScriptAccess%20attribute&source=bl&ots=Gjv1-arxv2&sig=ACfU3U3izWym4z1E5pwm_LcW4PY9fhY-Zg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifiPrFtOTgAhVObVAKHci-A6AQ6AEwBHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=AllowScriptAccess%20attribute&f=false) [links](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/semantics-embedded-content.html#the-embed-element) suggest.

Therefore my answer would be:

1. **No.** Not in an embed-tag.
2. **Yes.** I would disallow the embed-tag to secure your application.

As suggested in [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/204597/how-to-prevent-xss-in-user-generated-content-html-without-disabling-scripts-an/204607#204607) you could also consider to use a different domain for the user content and let the same origin policy aid you.